# How do you catch a Save or Load event on a Linq-to-SQL class?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a Linq-to-SQL class, and I'd like to perform some pre-save validation before the record is persisted to the DB.  In addition, once it has been saved, I'd like to have some post-save processing code.

Similarly, when a record is deleted, I'd like to have pre- and post- methods that will be called, no matter from where the `context.SubmitChanges()` call is made.

I don't see any methods in the generated code that I can override.  The partial method `OnValidate()` may be sufficient for the pre-processing, but I want to ability to cancel the save if certain conditions are not met, and I don't see any hooks at all for post-processing.

Am I missing something?  Or can you recommend another way of achieving the intended effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For inserts:

1. Create a base class for your entities.
2. Add some virtual methods.
3. Override `DataContext.SubmitChanges`.
4. Call `DataContext.GetChangeSet()` and iterate over the inserts applying the function you defined previously.

For reverting changes, look at my [extension method](http://xacc.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/datacontextrevertchanges/).

Comment: Thank you - didn't realize SubmitChanges was virtual!  Between you & Marc Gravell getting answer credit is a tough call, but I'll give it to you on account of the link to the extension method for reverting changes.  And also because ah lahk souf effricuns.  Baie dankie, boet!  ;)

Answer (score 4):

Well, throwing an exception will effectively cancel the change... a bit harsh though, perhaps.

Another extension point is by overriding the `SubmitChanges` on the data-context, to get the pending changes (`GetChangeSet`), do any final changes (auditing, perhaps), and then call the `base.SubmitChanges`. You could put any post-save operations *after* this (using the change-set you obtained before the save).